# Issue with the Foreach loop, coming out of loop once find the first first condition

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I am trying to loop through a xml node and its `childNode`. While doing that i am trying to check if a `dataList` contains the childNode inner value, if it's not there in List i am deleting the parent node form the xml. but the problem i am facing is that after finding the first condition the `foreach` loop is getting ended and stats from top `for` loop. Please find he code below: 
 **Update**
 `List<XmlNode> deletenode = new List<XmlNode>();`

```
for (int i = 0; i < xmlNodeList.Count; i++)
{
    deletenode = new List<XmlNode>();
    foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodeList[i].ChildNodes) 
    {
        if (node.Name == "testNode") 
        {  
            XmlNode delNode = node;
            if (node.ChildNodes[0].Name.ToString() == "nodeName")
            {
                string[] childNodesplit = node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText.Split(',');
                if (!dataList.Any(e => e.Equals(childNodesplit[0].ToString())))
                {                                            
                    delNode = node.ChildNodes[0].ParentNode;                                           
                    deletenode.Add(delNode);                       
                }                                        
            }
        }
    }
   foreach (XmlNode nd in deletenode)
   {
    if (nd.Name == "testNode")
    {
      ElemList[i].RemoveChild(nd);
    }

  }
}
```

can anyone point the mistake i am doing inside foreach loop, so that it wont comeout of the loop on matching one condition.
 I updated my code, but i am not able to get these node deleted.
**UPDATE**
 I got the solution now, i was missing to make the `deletenode` list as new for each loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You remove the parent of the node, children of whom you running over in the loop.

```
delNode = node.ChildNodes[0].ParentNode;  //PARENT !                                
xmlNodeList[i].RemoveChild(delNode);  //REMOVE
```

If you have to remove them, you might:

- save them into the separate list
- at the end of the function iterate over that list and remove all nodes 
    inside it, one by one

Comment: do i have save them in a separate `XmlNodeList`.

Comment: @SDLBeginner: you don't *have to*, but that is one of possible solutions, yes.

Comment: i added my updated code, but i am not able to delete these nodes.

Comment: thank you for you help and suggestions, i got the issue. I am updating solution in question.